# openshift 3.11 oc command : error: Error loading config file ".kube/config": yaml: line 11: could not find expected ':'

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-client-tools, openshift-3, okd

In a okd cluster installed using https://github.com/openshift/origin/tree/release-3.11

After the okd installation the oc command was working fine but after somedays, I'm facing a weird issue with oc command i.e running any oc command in the cluster is giving

```
[kubenode@master ~]$ oc status
error: Error loading config file "/home/kubenode/.kube/config": yaml: line 11: could not find expected ':'
```

The permission of the `/home/kubenode/.kube/config` is :

```
[kubenode@master ~]$ ls -al /home/kubenode/.kube/config
-rwx------. 1 kubenode kubenode 6102 Dec 11 00:30 /home/kubenode/.kube/config
```

While trying to solve this, what I have done is,
Empty the file `/home/kubenode/.kube/config` and copy the content of `/etc/origin/master/admin.kubeconfig` to `/home/kubenode/.kube/config`

This has solved the problem but its temporary solution because after some time(few hours) again i get the issue.
What could be the root cause for this and what can be the permanent fix?

Comment: try to run oc login instead of copying the kube.config

Comment: i have tried this as well, but after some time i get the same issue again

Comment: can you share the kube.config as well?

Answer (score 0):

This is the intended behaviour, as Access tokens and Authorize codes are supposed to only have a limited lifetime.

You should review the [Configuring authentication and user agent](https://docs.okd.io/3.11/install_config/configuring_authentication.html#token-options) documentation to set the following options to your liking (for example much longer timeouts) in your `/etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml` on your Master Nodes:

```
oauthConfig:
  ...
  tokenConfig:
    accessTokenMaxAgeSeconds: 86400 
    authorizeTokenMaxAgeSeconds: 300 
  ...
  sessionConfig:
    sessionMaxAgeSeconds: 300
```

Note that you'll need to apply these settings to all Master Nodes in your cluster. After changing the settings, remember to restart the API and the Controllers using the following commands:

```
# master-restart api
# master-restart controllers
```

Comment: Yes oc login session expires after certain duration. Here the issue is not that. If you check the error in the question it says `Error loading config file....` which says the kube/config file is not in proper format, due to this im not able to `oc login` at all. Updating `oauthConfig` will not solve my issue

Comment: Thanks, I think this should be clarified in your original post as well then. Also, as others have noted, please post the invalid `.kube/config` file so it can be reviewed.

Comment: Try to execute "oc logs master-api-<hostname> -n kube-system". You might get some useful information.